# How to compare two periods of time properly using "nearly as(or the) same" in the sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

I want to compare two periods of time and say that the current one is not "nearly the same as it was in 2010". How to say this sentence properly? (Or should I use "nearly as same as it was"?)

Comment: How are the time periods expressed? In what manner are the periods "nearly the same"?

Comment: For example, I would like to talk about cryptocurrency. In 2017 there was more hype than it is now. I try to say that what happens now is not nearly the same as it was in 2017 because in 2017 the hype was natural and organic.

Comment: I’d use “very different from” rather than “not nearly the same,” to emphasize the change.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. On Twitter I see people use the structure "it's not nearly the same as " (example https://twitter.com/sarahthemoose/status/1398667559021338624) and in other cases, I see people using "it's not nearly as same as ". Now I'm confused and not sure which one is correct

Comment: _As same as_ is incorrect English.#

Answer (score 0):

I would second Xanne's comment above and favor the use of "very different from" in this context.

I think "not nearly" is better suited to quantitative discussions, not qualitative ones.

For example:
"There weren't nearly as many complaints this year" is fairly clear in meaning.

But saying "this year is not nearly the same as last year" is, I feel, rather ambiguous and awkward for a native English reader.